# Passing multiple values to a substitute variable and iterating in query

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, sqlplus

Am looking to automate the substitute variable parmater passing for SQL

I have a select query with a substitute variable "&&a" which need to run against user input multiple times 
 am looking to automate the user input process by passing parameters/arguments in a text file.

sample code which requires user input:

```
Accept VARIABLEA char prompt "enter value for variable"
variable count number
col output new_val SELECTION

begin
select column_name from table_name where column_name='&&A';
end:/
```

&&A value should be picked up from text file and execute til end of file

Example:

```
Text file:
Abc
Gef
Hij
```

Query:

```
Select column_name from table_name where column_name='Abc';

Select column_name from table_name where column_name='Gef';
```

I tried passing text file as `"sqlplus usernam/passwd @query 'cat textfile'`

I could pick first value facing issues in reading next values

Can you help me with approach on achieving this

Comment: Do you want to call the script once passing multiple values into it, or do you want to call the script once per value?

Comment: Is the text file on the same OS file system as the database? Also, why are you using a text file to pass parameters to an autonomic database process? Finally, what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Perhaps you want to build something like `where somecolumn in (val1, val2, val3, ...)`, with val1 etc read from a file. How is the file structured?

Comment: @wiliam.. I need to read the each argument once and execute..

Comment: @Apc... No this text file  on my unix server

Comment: Sample. Txt       abc/ngef/ntgf/N......

Comment: You're looking to automate a user-interactive script. What's the use case? Why not replace the script with a stored procedure? Where does the output from the queries go? And again, **which version of Oracle are you using**? I can think of several different ways to approach this but which is appropriate for you depends on the specific requirements. You need to provide more details.

Comment: Oracle 12c version

Comment: I wanna automate this user interactive for automation of sql deployment of my application.... Queries are some delete and insert.. I gave select for reference... I cannot modify the user interactive sql query by procedure as it is vendor given...

Comment: @APC.. Any ideas to figure out an approach